Can't resolve service in Kubernetes
I have a pod that wants to connect to Redis, but we use dragonfly instead, but it can’t do that.
[2024-04-01 14:34:28.421 DEBUG common_server/src/db/redis_manager.rs:112] creating redis pool with CLIENT NAME: rust-rpauth-5b56497fcf-nz8gt|strict|2
[2024-04-01 14:34:34.444 ERROR common_server/src/db/redis_manager.rs:468] connection error in rust-rpauth-5b56497fcf-nz8gt|strict|2 : failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known
[2024-04-01 14:34:53.657 ERROR common_server/src/db/redis_manager.rs:468] connection error in rust-rpauth-5b56497fcf-nz8gt|strict|2 : failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known
[2024-04-01 14:34:53.659 ERROR common_server/src/db/redis_manager.rs:468] connection error in rust-rpauth-5b56497fcf-nz8gt|strict|2 : failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known
thread 'main' panicked at common_server/src/db/redis_manager.rs:120:14:
failed to create new redis pool: Error(Some("failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known"))
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
[2024-04-01 14:34:58.421 DEBUG common_server/src/providers/dispatch_data.rs:124] Dropping ServiceData

Checked the service - it works:
kubectl get endpoints -nrp-dev-dragonfly
NAME        ENDPOINTS        AGE
dragonfly   10.46.0.7:6379   4d23h
---
kubectl port-forward svc/dragonfly 6379:6379 -n rp-dev-dragonfly
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:6379 -> 6379
Forwarding from [::1]:6379 -> 6379
Handling connection for 6379

I created a simple pod with Ubuntu just to test whether my service is visible at all via nslookup (2'nd and 3'rd screenshot)
root@ubuntu:/# nslookup dragonfly.rp-dev-dragonfly.svc.cluster.local
Server:     10.80.0.10
Address:    10.80.0.10#53

** server can't find dragonfly.rp-dev-dragonfly.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN
root@ubuntu:/# 
root@ubuntu:/# 
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.80.0.10
search rp-dev.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
root@ubuntu:/#

While the same service is easily visible through the same command in other cluster with same services and was deployed using the same manifests.
I've been struggling with this problem for 2 days now, but I still can't figure out which direction to look. Thanks in advance for your help)

Hi. Could you add your coredns config, pls?
Here's additional info about what CoreDNS is and how to use it in Kubernetes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/

I'd also check whether or not NetworkPolicies block UDP/53 egress traffic from the pod, like in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71127697/7427923
